# Mystery Pipe in the Garden (UK)

Tags: pipe

Could anyone in the UK give me an idea what this pipe might be? It's sticking out of the ground about 0.5m from the back wall of my house. It seems to be capped off with a wired-shut cap or something. I'm hoping it's not gas - but I'm not sure.

The problem is that I've come to lay a new lawn where a flower bed was and found it, and it sticks up well past the level of the new lawn! :(

[image: Mystery Pipe]

Answer (score 1):

it's difficult to determine without a scale reference, but if I found this sort of thing in my yard, my first inclination would be to tap on it to determine that it's a solid rod and the suspect cap is a clamp used to attach grounding cables. The shape of the top of the rod/pipe appears to be the result of hammering the rod into the earth. In the USA, one can expect an 8 foot (>2 meter) long rod to meet specifications of many areas of the country.

Comment: Thanks Fred, some other people have suggested an old earth spike. I'm still trying to figure out if I need it or not...

Comment: @daklone Probably not ... there is nothing connected to it any more.

Comment: Thanks guys. In the end I decided that I didn't need it but rather than dig it up I just knocked it into the ground about 8" and left it.